# A doubt regarding the need for lemma 52.3 in Munkres' "Topology".

Tags: algebraic-topology

Munkres defines a simply connected space $X$ as:

> A path connected space in which $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is the trivial one-element group for some $x_0\in X$, and hence for every $x_0\in X$.

He then goes on to **prove** that in a simply connected space $X$, any two paths having the same initial and final points are homotopic.

Why is such a proof required? Doesn't the fact that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ contains only the identity element $[e_{x_{0}}]$ already prove that any two paths starting and ending at $x_0$ will homotopic?

Thanks.

Comment: The two paths, say $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, only share a starting point, say $x_1$, and an endpoint, say $x_2$. You seem to think that $x_1=x_2=x_0$, but this assumption is lifted here.

Comment: This kind of thing seems to me to be clearer if one uses the fundamental **groupoid** $\pi_1 X$. Then one has a more conceptual description of path connected and simply connected in terms of conditions on the fundamental groupoid. Groupoids of that type might be thought "trivial" but in fact a nice one has two objects $0,1$ and on ly one morphism $\iota:0 \to 1$ and this is a nice model of the unit interval, so deals with homotopies.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental group concerns loops, i.e. paths for which the final point and the initial one coincide. If you have two paths which are not loops, but such that they share the same initial and final points, that claim is true but it needs a proof, since it does not follow "directly" from the triviality of $\pi_1$.